# matplotlib scatter, pull data from column, only show newest data point

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scatter

How do I pull data from columns 4 and 5 on a csv file? Also how do I only show the most recent data point? The older points can disappear.

Below is what I have so far and below that is an example of the csv file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


def animate(i):
    pullData = open("sampleText.csv","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []

    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))

    ax1.scatter(xar,yar)

    ax1.set_xlim([-100, 100])
    ax1.set_xlabel('X')

    ax1.set_ylim([-100, 100])
    ax1.set_ylabel('Y')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Example CSV, File contains no header. Column 4 is 'x' and 5 is 'y'.

```
1,2,54,-34,54,23,65,
2,3,54,-34,-98,12,43,
3,6,54,34,56,76,89,
87,90,54,34,23,43,98,
44,98,54,-34,65,34,23,
23,79,54,34,-98,23,12,
9,3,54,34,65,34,32,
```

Comment: What do you want to plot? What is the x and y in the csv?

Comment: Column 4 and 5 in the example csv. 4 is x and 5 is y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eachLine.split(',')` returns a list like this (the last elemente empty is for the last comma of the csv):

```
['1', '2', '54', '-34', '54', '23', '65', '']
```

But that is already a list! Beware that the last element is `''`.

Then changed:

```
x,y = eachLine.split(',')
xar.append(int(x))
yar.append(int(y))
```

For this:

```
data = eachLine.split(',')
xar.append(int(data[-3]))
yar.append(int(data[-2]))
```

Finally to plot the last point, iterate over dataArray, so data is the last line of the csv.

```
pullData = open("sampleText.csv","r").read()
dataArray = pullData.split('\n')

for eachLine in dataArray:
    if len(eachLine)>1:
        data = eachLine.split(',')

# In this example data is: ['9', '3', '54', '34', '65', '34', '32', '']
plt.scatter(data[-3],data[-2])
plt.xlim([-100, 100])
plt.ylim([-100, 100])
```

[image: single_point]

Comment: Awesome Lucas! You nailed it. Now I just need to find a way to only show the newest data point. e.g. a new line is added to the csv. All previous data points on the plot can be discarded.

Comment: I see your last edit. Was this addressing the removal of the old data points leaving only the newest x,y measurement in the plot? Once I made the edits within "Finally to plot the last point:" it seems to function the same as before. All the data points in the csv appear in the plot. I need only the most recent or bottom line on the csv.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear about the csv file. The csv file is constantly being updated with new lines of data. Your example above shows ['9', '3', '54', '34', '65', '34', '32', ''] and that x,y data point is mapped in the plot. Moments later the csv file is updated with a new line of data and a new y,x location.

Comment: I would like the previous data point, ['9', '3', '54', '34', '65', '34', '32', ''], to disappear and the new x,y data point to be displayed.  The idea is to show movement. One data point moving across the plot triggered by the new csv entries.